# "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present" when starting a foreach loop on query result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, linq-to-entities, azure-sql-database

I have this query:

```
 // _db derives from DbContext
 var toProcess = from jobItem in _db.Jobs
                 where jobItem.State == desiredState
                 select jobItem.ItemId;
 foreach (Guid itemId in toProcess ) //exception thrown on this line
 {
     // whatever
 }
```

which most of the times runs fine, but once in a while the line with `foreach` will throw:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

with the following stack trace:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumnHeader(Int32 i)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i)
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetColumnValueWithErrorHandling[TColumn](Int32 ordinal)
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
```

which doesn't make any sense. How do I resolve this?

Comment: That is a very curious error; looks like some kind of internal mess-up checking for rows; what version of .NET is this using?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: That's version 4.0

Comment: And what version of EF? 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3? Have you tried to update?

Comment: Random question; is there any chance someone has issued a `SET FMTONLY ON` or a `SET ROWCOUNT [n]` on your connection? This looks *so odd* that I'm just trying to rule out likely causes

Comment: is the itemID nullable in the database?

Comment: @abatishchev: That's EF 4.2, I won't blindly update just to see if it fixes this minor problem.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: My code doesn't do anything like that.

Comment: @Carl: No, `ItemId` is not nullable.

Comment: What's happening in the `// whatever` lines? Does it take time?

Comment: @yamen: There's some medium weight activity that is expected to be done within several seconds but I guess it can take longer. Do you think a timeout happens?

Comment: If foreach runs longer try to increase connection timeout. [Here might be the same problem](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm/linq-questions/invalid-attempt-to-read-when-no-data-is-present.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As per your response to my comment:

> There's some medium weight activity that is expected to be done within
>   several seconds but I guess it can take longer. Do you think a timeout
>   happens?

I imagine that it's a timeout or something similar. You could **increase the timeout**, or you could just **force it to evaluate** and be stored in memory for later processing. You can do this by adding `ToArray()` at the end of the query:

```
 var toProcess = (from jobItem in _db.Jobs
                 where jobItem.State == desiredState
                 select jobItem.ItemId).ToArray();
```

See if that helps.